# Synonymize [merged-questions] and [merge-questions]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Should [merged-questions](/questions/tagged/merged-questions) (x 72, +excerpt, +wiki), be a master synonym of [merge-questions](/questions/tagged/merge-questions) (x6, no excerpt, no wiki)?

The latter seems to have been used within the context of [merged-questions](/questions/tagged/merged-questions).

Comment: I rather burninate [tag:merge-questions]

Comment: @rene it would probably come back if you did that instead of make it a synonym

Comment: Why @Malachi ? If the tag has no questions by 03:00 UTC it gets deleted. It will only re-appear if a high-rep user adds it to a question.

Comment: @rene that is what I am saying, I guess I haven't had much of that kind of experience on a graduated site. but some users don't always pay attention to all the tag changes on their site. I think it would be better as a synonym. they are very close, and what harm would it do?  6 people have already tagged it on their questions...

Answer (score 8):

From the Comments it looks like this should be an answer so that the community can decide whether or not it is a good idea.

I think that it should be a Synonym.

If we Burninate (delete) it, it could come back if someone, that doesn't know it was Burninated, edits it into a question or adds it as a tag on a new question.

This kind of thing happens all over the network, users trying to do good things don't know about all the Burninated tags and accidents happen, then a mod needs to go and Burninate the tag all over again.

By making it a Synonym there is no need to maintain it further, and these tags are, for all intents and purposes, the same.

What harm will it do to Synonymize them?